# unable to return String in Java

Tags: java, string, return-value

```
import java.io.*;   import java.lang.*;
public class basics{

    String input()throws IOException{
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String type=br.readLine();
        return  type;
    }

    String work(String S){
        int whitespace; int count=0;    String wrd=new String[5]
        int lenghth=S.length();
        int t=0;
        while(t<length){
            if(S.charAt(t)=='') {   
                whitespace++;
                count++;
            }
            else{
                wrd[count]+=S.charAt(t);
            }
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  n;
            String blank="";
            for(int j=1;j<6;j++){
                n = rand.nextInt(4) + 0;
                blank.append(wrd[n]);
            }
            return blank;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        System.out.println("enter a sentence of five words");
        String x;   x.input();  
        String output=work(x);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

This code is to jumble word of a five word sentence and produce a output, problem raised is this that the methods aren't returning string, what to do ?

Comment: You should really try to read the error message and make your question more descriptive (I guess your code does not compile, but you never mention that). "aren't returning string" doesn't really tell us anything. Try to use positive phrases ("the compiler talks about foo") as opposed to negative ones ("it does not do foo").

Comment: There must be a return statement for every possible condition. So if you are checking for conditions in your method, you will have to return for both cases, which can be done by either using return outside all if statements and while statements inside the method or by using return statement in each condition.

Comment: One more thing, you should focus on the error messages by compilers. They are there to help you. They will tell point you to the error while also suggesting the solutions in most cases. You didn't mention any lines where the error popped up so it makes me think you are not paying proper attention to the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After indenting the code properly, you can see that there's no `return` statement outside the `while(t<length)` in `work` method. If there's no output for that case, then return an empty string or throw an exception.

```
String work(String S){
    int whitespace; int count=0;    String wrd=new String[5]
    int lenghth=S.length();
    int t=0;
    while(t<length){
        if(S.charAt(t)=='') {   
            whitespace++;
            count++;
        }
        else{
            wrd[count]+=S.charAt(t);
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n;
        String blank="";
        for(int j=1;j<6;j++){
            n = rand.nextInt(4) + 0;
            blank.append(wrd[n]);
        }
        return blank;
    }
    //HERE
    return ""; // or return a proper default value
}
```